# How to Make Deep Copy in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-data

As in copying both the entity's attributes and its relationships. Here's what I have right now:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    func makeCopy(copyRelations: Bool, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSManagedObject? {

        let entity = self.entity
        let copy = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        for (attrKey, _) in copy.entity.attributesByName {
            copy.setValue(value(forKey: attrKey), forKey: attrKey)
        }

        if copyRelations {
            let relations = copy.entity.relationshipsByName

            for (relKey, relValue) in relations {
                if relValue.isToMany {
                    let sourceSet = mutableSetValue(forKey: relKey)
                    let clonedSet = copy.mutableSetValue(forKey: relKey)
                    let enumerator = sourceSet.objectEnumerator()

                    while let relatedObject = enumerator.nextObject()  {
                        let clonedRelatedObject = (relatedObject as! NSManagedObject).makeCopy(copyRelations: false, context: context)
                        clonedSet.add(clonedRelatedObject!)
                    }
                } else {
                    copy.setValue(value(forKey: relKey), forKey: relKey)
                }
            }
        }

        return copy
    }
}
```

The major problem here is that it doesn't seem to be copying the relationships - though it also fails in a few unexpected ways - in short I know this isn't the right approach but haven't found any resources on what I should do instead.

Anyone know how to make a deep copy of a Core Data Entity in Swift?

Comment: Off topic but you have a property `entity` in `NSManagedObject` so you don't need the `name` parameter in your function.

Comment: Thanks, I guess using self just totally slipped my mind. Edited the snippet to remove `name`